# Scroll bar Style change in all browser?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, css

Is there any strong CSS or jQuery in web technology which can change style of scroll-bar in all browsers .I want to change default full width window screen scroll bar style.

Comment: not much in CSS. However there are quite a few jquery scroll bar plugins that you can use.

Comment: @NareshKumar Here's a demo page for Webkit browsers: http://trac.webkit.org/export/41842/trunk/LayoutTests/scrollbars/overflow-scrollbar-combinations.html

Comment: http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll this may also work for you

Answer (score 7):

This one is highly configurable and works great: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/

Lots of examples and documentation available.

Demo for full page scroll:
http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/fullpage_scroll.html

Answer (score 1):

The following CSS won't work in Internet Explorer, Microsoft Edge, or Firefox:

```
/*used to determine the width of scroll bar*/
::-webkit-scrollbar
{width:5px;}

/*where the draggable handle moves*/
::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{background:#212121;}

/*defining the draggable handle*/
::-webkit-scrollable-thumb
{background:#f1f1f1; border-radius:2.5px}

/*hovering over draggable handle*/
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover
{background:#555;}
```